# Consumir API en Solidity Blockchain

Tags: mysql, nodejs, solidity, blockchain

Estoy intentando traer unos datos de un API montada con NODE.JS y Mysql a Solidity para ingresarlos en un mensaje de transacción en un contrato inteligente, pero no encuentro la documentación para hacer el llamado a la API, alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo? Agradezco sus comentarios

Comment: Desde node hacia tu api debes usar algo como axios.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, me puedes dar mas información porfa? por que ya la API esta lista y funcional, lo que necesito saber es como llamar los datos de la api desde solidity

Comment: Sin código es muy difícil darte una respuesta. Pon el código del cual tienes duda y un ejemplo de lo que quieres realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Resumen: usa un oraculo.

Primero: el blockchain no permite el acceso a datos externo desde un smartcontract, me refiero a que un contrato no puede llamar a una api.

Razon: Todas las operaciones en una blockchain deben ser inmutables en el tiempo, si llamas a una api hoy y te responde 1 y la llamas mañana y te responde 2, eso romperia la inmutabilidad.

Segundo: Si es posible guardar datos en un smartcontract desde una api, puedes usar un webhook para que cuando llames a tu api, esta se conecte al smartcontract y guarde datos en el, pero si tu api es vulnerada probablemente el smartcontrar sea vulnerado tambien.

Solucion: Usar un oraculo, puedes crear el tuyo propio o usar el proveedor mas popular es chainlink, cada llamada a chain link tiene un costo pero ofrecen una infraestructura relativamente robusta y soporte en muchas redes.